# Fourth degree equation with parameter

Tags: polynomials, parametric

For what values of the parameter *a* equation $$x^4-a*x^3+(3-2a)*x^2+a*x+1=0$$ has both positive and negative roots?

Comment: We can show that $$a = (x^4+3*x*x+1)/(x^3-2*x*x+x)$$, but the function $$f(x) = (x^4+3*x*x+1)/(x^3-2*x*x+x)$$ is very difficult to analyze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$x=0$$ is not a solution, we can divide by $$x^2$$ and we get:
$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+a\left(-x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+3-2a=0$$. Now Substitute $$t=-x+\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Thank you, and what is the next step?

Comment: You will get $$t^2+2=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$$ and solve the quadratic.

Comment: And where is the *a* parameter now?

Comment: It is $$t^2+2+at+3-2a=0$$ to solve.

Comment: How it helps with finding both positive and negative roots?

Comment: You must use the quadratic formula!

Comment: So, $$-x+1/x = (-a +- sqrt(a*a-4*(5-2*a)))/2$$

Comment: Now multiply by $x$ and solve the equation.

Comment: $$t_{1,2}=-\frac{a}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4}+2a-5}$$

Comment: Yes, but now we have two equations, because of $±$, how to find an *a*?

Comment: Actually, $$-x+1/x=c (c=const)$$ always has both positive and negative solutions. So we just need the discriminant $$D=a^2+8a-5>=0$$

Comment: A connected question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2995124  where the term "reciprocal equation" is to be noticed (here it corresponds to the fact that if $r$ is a root - real of complex - of the given polynomial $-1/r$ is as well a root).

Answer (score 1):

The discriminant of your polynomial is $(8a^2 - 4a + 1)(a + 10)^2(a - 2)^2$.

Note that $0$ is never a root, so the numbers of positive and negative real roots can only change when $a$ is one of the roots of the discriminant, namely $a=2$ and $a=-10$.

For $ a < -10$ there are two positive and two negative real roots.  At $a = -10$ the two positive roots and the two negative roots collide, making the polynomial $(x^2+5x-1)^2$.
For $-10 < a < 2$, there are no real roots at all (e.g. for $a=0$ the polynomial is $x^4 + 3 x^2 + 1$).
For $a=2$, the polynomial is $(x^2-x-1)^2$ which has 
two double roots, one positive and one negative.
For $a > 2$, there are two positive and two negative real roots.

So the answer is: $a \le -10$ or $a \ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation can be written under the form :

$$\underbrace{\dfrac{x^4+3x^2+1}{x^3+2x^2-x}}_{f(x)}=a \tag{1}$$

which is the equation for the abscissas of intersection points of the curve with equation $y=f(x)$ and the horizontal line $y=a$.

Therefore our issue can be re-formulated equivalently into "not all the intersections points (if they are some...) have a same sign for their abscissas".

A quick look at the figure below shows that if

> $$a \notin (-10,2)\tag{2}$$

the condition is fulfilled (same result as @Robert Israel).

Remark : in fact, line $y=a$ for $-10<a<2$ has even no intersection points with the curve.

[image]

The graphic below is convincing : we can even say that, under condition (2), there are always 2 positive roots and 2 negative roots.

BUT a rigorous proof would necessitate a study of the variations of function $f$ (through the study of the sign of $f'(x)$), knowing that

$$f(x)=x-2+\dfrac{8x^2-2x+1}{x^3+2x^2-x}=x-2-\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{9x+2}{x^2+2x-1}\tag{3}$$

Comment: It's an obvious solution and the plot is quiet difficult to build, I mentioned it before.

Comment: Yes, but you hadn't the good denominator...